# concrete uses of LDAP?

Tags: linux, ldap

im new to LDAP.

i wonder what are some concrete examples of using LDAP.

things that are MUCH more easier to do when you got 3-7 linux computers in a small company network.

one use that is very important for me seems to be that you configure LDAP to handle system authentication. then you dont have to create same accounts in all computers.

are there other things that are a MUST DO for a small network to save more time?

my small network is for apache servers and database servers.

and should LDAP be in an own machine? cause i guess its not good to put it in apache or database servers since these are performance dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put LDAP in a machine where some other services are available : it doesn't take a lot of RAM nor CPU.
You can authenticate your users, configure your mail server to use it, with list sharing in mail clients, and even use it to store your DNS entries.
You can authenticate your users on web sites too. 
If they change their password, all your applications have the new password.

It supports monitoring, ACL, and a lot of optimizations. LDAP is very good for reading and a little bit slow in writing but, on actual hardware, there is no problem.

Just think : make backups, to restart your infrastructure if the LDAP directory goes down...

Answer (score 4):

LDAP is an *excellent* hierarchical object store. Things that *could* be done with a key-value or relational store, but would require more power. That's why it's great for a directory. An authdb just happens to be a degenerate form of a directory.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my compilation of LDAP uses i did for my company.

1. /etc/hosts, networks, fstab, aliases, protocols, rpc etc.  to LDAP. padl
2. SSH Public Keys based authentication via PAM modules. Good tutorials available [here.](http://code.google.com/p/openssh-lpk/wiki/Main)
3. Per host access control via netgroups. More info [here](http://www.sunmanagers.org/pipermail/summaries/2002-January/000604.html) and [here.](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Howto:Netgroups) Also see access.conf and host attribute.
4. Manage /etc/sudoers in LDAP and migration is easy and lots of info [here.](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/man/sudoers.ldap.html)
5. HOST inventory and statistics in LDAP with realtime update from hosts. I propsed this [here.](http://www.mail-archive.com/fedora-directory-users@redhat.com/msg10258.html)

Lots and lots can be implemented via LDAP for its directory structure. Like Automount, Postfix and sendmail, homedirectories, DHCP etc.

The replication in LDAP makes it even a better candidate for redundancy. But again don;t make it a bottle-neck of your network. Careful planning and metrics need to be done before selecting any tool.

Feel free to contact me with any questions related to LDAP.

See [here](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Documentation) for 389-DS specific guides.